# how to track Magento 2 admin updates for development?

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2. On Magento 1, we can use something called `mageploy`. Mageploy helps us to record actions for admin configurations, cms pages, cms blocks, and other, then when other developer pulls the codes and executes the command, they will get the same updates.